# Specifying bash command as variable and then executing during runtime

Tags: arrays, bash, function, variables, echo

How do I specify the command `date` as a variable so that it is executed upon calling said variable?

```
DATE=`date +%H:%M:%S`
echo "$DATE"
sleep 5
echo "$DATE" # Date displays the original time, not the current one
```

--

**EDIT 1**:
According to *anubhava*'s suggestion:

```
freshdate[0]=`date +%H:%M:%S`
```

However, this does not result in:

```
echo "${freshdate[0]}"  # 19:25:50
sleep 5
echo "${freshdate[0]}"  # 19:25:50
```

Comment: Use a function or array to store command line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to wrap this command in a shell function like this:

```
dt() { date '+%H:%M:%S'; }
```

Then use it anywhere you want to access it as in:

```
echo "Time now is: $(dt)"
Time now is: 13:34:30
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

You can do

```
DATE=(date +%H:%M:%S)
${DATE[@]}
sleep 5
${DATE[@]}
```

and will show different times.

Comment: Yes, that prints the new time, but I would like to `echo` the new time (i.e., integrate it into a longer string). Something along the line of `echo "Foo bar baz $DATE[@]"`. How do I do that?